How do I fix cors access control missing header?
This is my js function:
btn = document.getElementById('submit-button')
    btn.addEventListener("click",submitForm)
    function submitForm(){
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/diagnose', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({ symptoms: symptoms, email: loggedInUser.email }),
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            if (resultDiv) {
                displayResults(data, symptoms);
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
            if (resultDiv) {
                resultDiv.innerHTML = '<p style="color: red;">An error occurred while processing your request. Please try again.</p>';
            }
        });
    }

This is my server code. I've tried to include what the method I am calling, and my imports and anything that might be relevant.
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_from_directory
import json
import os
import traceback

app = Flask(__name__)
ALLOWED_ORIGIN = os.environ.get('ALLOWED_ORIGIN', 'http://localhost:5500')
# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Path to users.json and history file
history_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'history.json')
users_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'users.json')


# Middleware function to handle CORS headers
def add_cors_headers(response):
    # Only allow requests from your frontend domain
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://localhost:5500'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization'
    return response

# Register the after_request handler
@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    return add_cors_headers(response)

# Handle OPTIONS requests
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''}, methods=['OPTIONS'])
@app.route('/<path:path>', methods=['OPTIONS'])
def handle_options(path):
    return '', 204


# Diagnose route
@app.route('/diagnose', methods=['POST'])
def diagnose():
    data = request.json
    symptoms = data.get('symptoms', '')
    email = data.get('email', '')
    diagnosis, recommendation = diagnose_and_recommend(symptoms)

    # save history
    history = read_history()
    history['history'].append({
        "email": email,
        "date": datetime.now().isoformat(),
        "symptoms": symptoms,
        "diagnosis": diagnosis,
        "recommendation": recommendation
    })
    write_history(history)

    return jsonify({
        "diagnosis": diagnosis,
        "recommendation": recommendation
    })



# Static files route
@app.route('/<path:filename>')
def serve_static_files(filename):
    return send_from_directory('../', filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

I have tried to allow the headers as you'll see in the method labelled middleware but I am unfamiliar with cors. I would like to do away with it completely, but I don't know how to get a response from my python file. I don't know if it matters but my app.py is in a backend folder, while the js is in the root folder.

does Handle OPTIONS requests add CORS headers as required?

@JaromandaX I don't know.

What is the EXACT error message

@JaromandaX From firefox dev tools: (Sorry I took a while I had class)
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://cors.io/?http://localhost:5000/diagnose. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 530.

your request is for localhost:5000 ... why is the error about cors.io?
